# Showing a module is not flat

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, flatness

Let us consider the finitely generated $k$-algebra $M=k[x,y,z]/(xy,yz,zx)$. Its Noether normalisation is $R=k[w]$, where $w=x+y+z$. Now I need to show that $M$ is not a flat $R$-module. For this it is enough to show that $M$ is torsion as $R$ is PID.

M is generated by $(1,x,y,z)$ as an $R$-module. So I need to find a torsion element in $M$. How do I find a torsion element in $M$? Is there a procedure?

Thank you.

Comment: I am pretty sure that $M$ is free with basis $1,x,y$.

Comment: Note that $z=w \cdot 1 - 1 \cdot x - 1 \cdot y$, hence you can leave out $z$ in the generating set. The remaining generators are linear independent.

Comment: Another approach: if $(x+y+z)f(x,y,z)=0$ then $(X+Y+Z)f(X,Y,Z)\in(XY,YZ,ZX)$. But $(XY,YZ,ZX)=(X,Y,)\cap(Y,Z)\cap(Z,X)$, an intersection of three prime ideals none of them containing $X+Y+Z$. The conclusion follows.

Comment: Btw, torsion module means that *all* its elements are torsion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments, I showed that $M$ is actually generated by $1,x,y$.

Note that this a linear independent set of generators, i.e. a basis:

Take a linear combination, which is zero:

$$0=f(w) \cdot 1 + g(w) \cdot x + h(w) \cdot y = f(x+y+z) + xg(x)+yh(y).$$

Assume $f \neq 0$. Note that $f$ cannot be constant, because the other summands do not admit constant terms to cancel the constant. Let $d > 0$ be the degree of $f$, then $f(x+y+z)$ admits the term $z^d$, which cannot be canceled by the other terms. Hence $f=0$ and from there it is trivial to see that $g=h=0$.

Summarizing, $M$ is a free $k[w]$-module of rank $3$.